# How can i compute the average of each column and row and print along the 10*3 array

Tags: python

I want it to print the averages as a another column and row
i also keep getting this error when i attempt to run it

File "desktop/exercise10.py", line 25, in 
a[i][n+1] = total / m
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
import stdio
a = [[99.0,85.0,98.0],
     [98.0,57.0,79.0],
     [92.0,77.0,74.0],
     [94.0,62.0,81.0],
     [99.0,94.0,92.0],
     [80.0,76.5,67.0],
     [76.0,58.5,90.5],
     [92.0,66.0,91.0],
     [97.0,70.5,66.5],
     [89.0,89.5,81.0]]
     
m = 10
n = 3
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        stdio.write(a[i][j])
        stdio.write(' ')
    stdio.writeln()

for i in range(m):
    total = 0.0
    for j in range(n):
        total += a[i][j]
    a[i][n] = total / m
 
for j in range(n):
    total = 0.0
    for i in range(m):
        total += a[i][j]
    a[m+1][j] = total / n
```

Comment: " i also keep getting this error when i attempt to run it" Well, do you think there should not be an error? Try to convince me of why there shouldn't be an error. Start by looking at the line of code mentioned in the error message, and explaining what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Are you allowed to use NumPy?

Comment: no i cant use numPy

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use append to insert an element in the end of a list. Check the code below:

```
a = [[99.0,85.0,98.0],
     [98.0,57.0,79.0],
     [92.0,77.0,74.0],
     [94.0,62.0,81.0],
     [99.0,94.0,92.0],
     [80.0,76.5,67.0],
     [76.0,58.5,90.5],
     [92.0,66.0,91.0],
     [97.0,70.5,66.5],
     [89.0,89.5,81.0]]

for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i].append(sum(a[i])/len(a[i]))

list_avg_column = []
for j in range(len(a[0])):
    avg_column = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        avg_column += a[i][j]
    list_avg_column.append(avg_column/len(a))
a.append(list_avg_column)

# print information
import stdio

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        stdio.write(a[i][j])
        stdio.write(' ')
    stdio.writeln()
```